# why is Django MultipleObjectsReturned Error hogging memory?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am using Django 1.9.10:

I have a model called `Details` has a `unique_id` column which is indexed:

```
 try:
     detail = Detail.objects.get(unique_id=UUID)
 except MultipleObjectsReturned as m:
     logger.error("uuid {} returned multiple objects - {}".format(UUID, str(m)))
```

Due to some error in code `UUID=None` this resulted in `MultipleObjectsReturned` error getting raised. but we noticed that almost 2-GB of memory is getting used up and it is slowing the system down a lot.

On printing str(m) in the error logs we found following error

> MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Details -- it returned 451424!

**My Question is why is Django fetching so much data in memory just to raise an error? Django can just fetch the count?**

I know I can use filter() to over come this issue but I am just surprised by this and want to understand why django is doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how it's done internally:

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Perform the query and return a single object matching the given
    keyword arguments.
    """
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs) # calling `filter()` inside
    if self.query.can_filter() and not self.query.distinct_fields:
        clone = clone.order_by()
    num = len(clone)
    if num == 1:
        return clone._result_cache[0]
    if not num:
        raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
            "%s matching query does not exist." %
            self.model._meta.object_name
        )
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
        "get() returned more than one %s -- it returned %s!" %
        (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
    )
```

See the full source [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L352).

I guess you wonder why it can't just fetch the number? Because it will make two requests to the database instead of one. One request to fetch the count and one request to fetch the data.

How can you fix it? You may change your application logic to avoid this situation. Assert that `UUID` is not `None`. Or fetch `count` before making an actual query.

Docs about `get`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get

Comment: Would it not be good idea to modified the get()  with a limit() on the filter query.  then just say that get() returned more than one  result, skip the count part and avoid breaking the system by not bringing so many records into memory

Comment: @Crazyshezy you can submit a ticket and a patch to the Django project if you think it's a valuable improvement.

Comment: @Crazyshezy so this is interesting. in 1.7 they had the limit as you are recommending. Not sure why they removed it later. check the code at https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/db/models/query.py

Answer (score 1):

Because you use .get when you know you shouldn't get multiple objects.

Choosing to use it in a case where 451424 items are returned instead isn't something it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have more then one with same ID in database.
Rewrite your query to this: `Detail.objects.filter(unique_id=UUID)`